# Alfresco: Class has not been defined in the data dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, alfresco

I am using Javascript to create a custom data list item from a workflow. The Javascript works if I use a default Alfresco data list, but not my custom one.

**Javascript excerpt from .bpmn file**

```
// Get the site name and dataLists 
var site = siteService.getSite("Testing");
var dataLists = site.getContainer("dataLists");

// Check for data list existence 
if (!dataLists) {
  var dataLists = site.createNode("dataLists", "cm:folder");

  var dataListProps = new Array(1);
  dataListProps["st:componentId"] = "dataLists";
  dataLists.addAspect("st:siteContainer", dataListProps);
  dataLists.save();
}

var orpList = dataLists.childByNamePath("orplist1");

if (!orpList) {
  var orpList = dataLists.createNode("orplist1","dl:dataList");

  // tells Share which type of items to create
  orpList.properties["dl:dataListItemType"] = "orpdl:orpDataListModel";
  orpList.save();

  var orpListProps = [];
  orpListProps["cm:title"] = "ORP List";
  orpListProps["cm:description"] = "A contact list generated by a javascript.";
  orpList.addAspect("cm:titled", orpListProps);
}

var opportunity = orpList.createNode(null, "orpdl:orpDataListModel")
opportunity.properties["orpdl:name"] = "Florian";
opportunity.save();
```

**Model Excerpts**

```
<model name="orpdl:orpDataListModel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">

<namespaces>
    <namespace uri="http://www.test.com/model/orpDataListModel/1.0" prefix="orpdl" />
</namespaces>
```

**Context bean**

```
<!-- Data List Model Registration -->
<bean id="${project.artifactId}_dictionaryBootstrapOrp" parent="dictionaryModelBootstrap" depends-on="dictionaryBootstrap">
    <property name="models">
        <list>
            <value>alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/model/orpDataListModel.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Error**

> org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Exception while invoking
>   TaskListener: Exception while invoking TaskListener: 06010019 Failed
>   to execute supplied script: Class
>   {http://www.test.com/model/orpDataListModel/1.0}orpDataListModel has
>   not been defined in the data dictionary

The data list operates perfectly on its own. What is the problem here?

Comment: Should you not have a `<type>` entry for `orpdl:orpDataListModel` in your model?

Comment: I do, is that the issue? Should I be referencing the type name and not the model name?

Comment: Looks like that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Alfresco model can contain 0 or more types, along with other things like constraints, aspects etc. You can read more about content modelling in the [Alfresco documentation on the subject](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/content-modeling-about.html?m=2)

As such, when you're creating a type, or setting a type onto a datalist, you need to use type's ID, and not the model it comes from

Your two problematic lines are therefore:

```
orpList.properties["dl:dataListItemType"] = "orpdl:orpDataListModel";

var opportunity = orpList.createNode(null, "orpdl:orpDataListModel");
```

For a custom datalist type with short qname `orpdl:orpList`, these should instead be:

```
orpList.properties["dl:dataListItemType"] = "orpdl:orpList";

var opportunity = orpList.createNode(null, "orpdl:orpList");
```

Some bits of Alfresco validate that you've given a valid type at creation time, but not all. Datalist item types is one area which doesn't validate until use, which is why you got as far as you did!

Comment: Kinda-related question: is it bad practice to use the same namespace for two different kinds of models? I.E., use "prefix:" for a data list model and workflow model?

Comment: Nope, we do it quite a bit, so that everything to do with one logical thing lives in the same model/namespace

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with my Javascript, as you need to use the **type name** and not the **model name**. Here is the finished working code, where *orp:orpList* is the type name defined in the model:

```
// Get the site name and dataLists 
var site = siteService.getSite("Testing");
var dataLists = site.getContainer("dataLists");

// Check for data list existence 
if (!dataLists) {
  var dataLists = site.createNode("dataLists", "cm:folder");

  var dataListProps = new Array(1);
  dataListProps["st:componentId"] = "dataLists";
  dataLists.addAspect("st:siteContainer", dataListProps);
  dataLists.save();
}

var orpList = dataLists.childByNamePath("orplist1");

if (!orpList) {
  var orpList = dataLists.createNode("orplist1","dl:dataList");

  // tells Share which type of items to create
  orpList.properties["dl:dataListItemType"] = "orpdl:orpList";
  orpList.save();

  var orpListProps = [];
  orpListProps["cm:title"] = "ORP List";
  orpListProps["cm:description"] = "A contact list generated by a javascript.";
  orpList.addAspect("cm:titled", orpListProps);
}

var opportunity = orpList.createNode(null, "orpdl:orpList")
opportunity.properties["orpdl:name"] = "Florian";
opportunity.save();
```

Comment: A model can contain multiple types, so for things like this, you always need to refer to the type and not the model it lives in